# Правильно ли оформлена прямая речь?

Tags: прямая-речь

В заключение так и хочется сказать по К. Марксу: "Производители всей страны, объединяйтесь
против санкций!"

Comment: Только это не цитата, а просто прямая речь автора (по Марксу).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, верно. Это цитата, оформляется как прямая речь.